# Socket programming between linux client and linux/windows server and android

Tags: android, python, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to send data from a Linux client to a Linux/Windows server (maybe a shared host)  and finally to an android application like this figure :

[image]

The data can be a text or stream video or audio.

What are the best technologies and languages for this scenario ? What is your suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up communication between same platform or cross platform clients/server. If you're sticking to *nix platform, you can try out with unix sockets. Since cross platform being a better option, you can implement the same thing using node.js and sockets. For better insight upon socket.io,please go through http://socket.io/